# java(android) import sequence lead to build fail

Tags: eclipse, import, build, sequence, javac

1. Outer.java is an interface
2. file structure:
     ---kyle(package)
        ------Main.java（it contains an subclass named InnerClass）
        ------out(package)
        ----------Outer.java
3. my puzzle is as follows:
   A. when the import of interface below the import of the Innerclass, compile mistake shown
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1MxM.jpg)
   B. when i change the order, it compiles correctly.
   [as you can see in this other screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrsAl.jpg)
4. there still is something that puzzled me: eclipse can compile it but javac cannot.
5. I have this error in my Android project, then i create the demo code to show my error.
   Thanks in advance. If you have any idea, just talk it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Eclipse has already transfered all .java files to .class?

Then it can  compile it, but sequence is important in javac when not in Eclipse!

Comment: I don't know your language. are u come from Nankai University. thanks as the same.